# Cómo mover componentes por separado en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ide

¡Que tal compañeros! Bien soy nuevo utilizando el IDE Android Studio y durante mis primeras pruebas y ejercicios en el me eh encontrado frustrado por la manera en la que se trabajan los componentes la causa es la siguiente al momento de insertar los componentes en la parte de diseño de la aplicación (Grafica) todo perfecto pero al mover alguno de ellos a otra posición se mueven todos, en otros IDE´s nunca me había topado con algo así o sea que puedo mover cada uno de los componentes a mi antojo.

Y pues eso, ¿es posible mover cada uno de los componentes? 
Si la respuesta es sí, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

[image: En la imagen el cursor está en el botón del lado izquierdo y lo estoy moviendo, pero todos los componentes en amarillo también siguen el mismo movimiento que realizo en el botón cuando lo único que quiero es que se mueva el botón del lado izquierdo que es el que tengo seleccionado…]

Comment: agrega el codigo de tu layout

Comment: En la imagen el cursor está en el botón del lado izquierdo y lo estoy moviendo, pero todos los componentes en amarillo también siguen el mismo movimiento que realizo en el botón cuando lo único que quiero es que se mueva el botón del lado izquierdo que es el que tengo seleccionado …

Comment: bien entiendo que puedo trabajar en el xml pero no es el caso quiero saber si es posible mover los componentes por separado desde el diseño y no en el texto del xml y ese ejemplo de la imagen es solo representativo  no preciso de una solución para este caso si no en general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si utilizas `RelativeLayout`, los componentes, se juntaran con alguna de estas propiedades:

- Si `android:layout_alignParentTop` es `true`, hace que el borde de arriba de la vista se encuentre con borde de arriba de la vista padre.
- Si `android:layout_centerVertical` es "true", centra la vista hija verticalmente a la vista padre.
- La propiedad `android:layout_below` posiciona el borde de arriba de la vista en el borde de abajo de la vista especificada por el *ID*.
- La propiedad `android:layout_toRightOf` posiciona el borde izquierdo de la vista al borde derecho de la vista especificada por el *ID*.

Con las últimas dos propiedades, si mueve una vista se moverán todas los relacionados a esta.

Eso, independiente de como estén anotados en el *XML*, pero siempre estarán asociados a una vista. Si no es así, se sobrepondrá con otra.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Otra forma es con el *LinearLayout*. Con este debes indicar si es horizontal o vertical, indicando cuánto espacio usará la vista en la línea.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Por lo tanto, moviendo uno de los componentes o cambiando el tamaño, afectará a todas las vistas que estén relacionadas en la vista padre.

Es aconsejable utilizar el diseñador y el *XML* para arreglar los componentes en particular, si solo intentas con el diseñador, tendrás muchos problemas similares.